# Why is tensorflow map_fn slower than python for loops

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I want to apply an independent rotation to each batch of points in a tensor with shape `[batch, n_pts, 3]`. I implemented it two separate ways. The first was to convert the tensor into a numpy array and a basic python for loops. The second uses tensorflows `tf.map_fn()` to eliminate the for loops. However, when I run this, the tensorflow `map_fn()` is ~100x slower.

My question is am I using the `tf.map_fn()` function incorrectly here. When would you expect to have a performance gain using the `tf.map_fn()` over standard numpy/python?

If I am using it correctly, then I would like to know why the tensorflow `tf.map_fn()` is so much slower.

My code to reproduce the experiment is:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K


def rotate_tf(pc):

    theta = tf.random.uniform((1,)) * 2.0 * np.pi
    cosval = tf.math.cos(theta)[0]
    sinval = tf.math.sin(theta)[0]

    R = tf.Variable([
        [cosval, -sinval, 0.0],
        [sinval, cosval, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
    ])

    def dot(p):
        return K.dot(R, tf.expand_dims(p, axis=-1))

    return tf.squeeze(tf.map_fn(dot, pc))


def rotate_np(pc):

    theta = np.random.uniform() * 2.0 * np.pi
    cosval = np.cos(theta)
    sinval = np.sin(theta)

    R = np.array([
        [cosval, -sinval, 0.0],
        [sinval, cosval, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
    ])

    for idx, p in enumerate(pc):
        pc[idx] = np.dot(R, p)

    return pc


pts = tf.random.uniform((8, 100, 3))
n = 10

# Start tensorflow map_fn() method
start = time.time()

for i in range(n):
    pts = tf.map_fn(rotate_tf, pts)

print('processed tf in: {:.4f} s'.format(time.time()-start))

# Start numpy method
start = time.time()

for i in range(n):

    pts = pts.numpy()
    for i, p in enumerate(pts):
        pts[i] = rotate_np(p)
    pts = tf.Variable(pts)

print('processed np in: {:.4f} s'.format(time.time()-start))
```

The output for this is:

```
processed tf in: 3.8427 s
processed np in: 0.0314 s
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the resources of the computer u used?
My guess is that TF is manipulating more complex objects (Tensors).

But you are not using TF at full capacity! TF has a [graph mode](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs). This feature will speedup your calculations.

When using small arrays, numpy outperforms TF (with the code below). For bigger data, I found that the reverse is True. I did some small modifications:

- @tf.function decorator
- removed the tf.Variable in rotate_tf
- removed numpy/tf convertions in for loop to get the execution time of the numpy for loop
- changed n and the batch size of *pts*

```
import time
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K


@tf.function(jit_compile=True, reduce_retracing=True)
def rotate_tf(pc):

    theta = tf.random.uniform((1,)) * 2.0 * np.pi
    cosval = tf.math.cos(theta)[0]
    sinval = tf.math.sin(theta)[0]

    R = tf.convert_to_tensor([
        [cosval, -sinval, 0.0],
        [sinval, cosval, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
    ])

    def dot(p):
        return K.dot(R, tf.expand_dims(p, axis=-1))

    return tf.squeeze(tf.map_fn(dot, pc))


def rotate_np(pc):

    theta = np.random.uniform() * 2.0 * np.pi
    cosval = np.cos(theta)
    sinval = np.sin(theta)

    R = np.array([
        [cosval, -sinval, 0.0],
        [sinval, cosval, 0.0],
        [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
    ])

    for idx, p in enumerate(pc):
        pc[idx] = np.dot(R, p)

    return pc


pts = tf.random.uniform((8, 100, 3))
n = 100

# Start tensorflow map_fn() method
start = time.time()

for i in range(n):
    pts = tf.map_fn(rotate_tf, pts)

print('processed tf in: {:.4f} s'.format(time.time()-start))

# Start numpy method
start = time.time()

pts = pts.numpy()
for i in range(n):

    for i, p in enumerate(pts):
        pts[i] = rotate_np(p)
    
print('processed np in: {:.4f} s'.format(time.time()-start))
```